# How to improve the performance of a query?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I have a query which I'd like to improve. For some reason the query needs 6-8s to get a response. I have already managed to improve the performance, but 6-8s is just too much. 
This is my first programming project and I don't understand what causes this slow performance/ what I should look for?

Some background:

- I'm using Next.js (serverless) and Postgres.
- The DB is hosted on Heroku.
- The code below is simplified (regarding my db). In reality I have 4 tables to left join and a few more columns.
- Each table has a primary key on the column `content` (=> clustered index, I checked it with EXPLAIN ANALYZE), so I didn't add any additional indexes.

Here's my code:

```
const content = itemData[0].contentList;
    const splitContent = content.split(", ");
    const contentArray =
      typeof splitContent === "string" ? [splitContent] : splitContent;
    const result = await knex("Cos")
      .leftJoin("Actives", "Cos.content", "ilike", "Actives.content")
      .leftJoin("Alcohol", "Cos.content", "ilike", "Alcohol.content")
      .column([
        "Cos.content",
        "function",
        "translationPlant",
        "categoryAlcohol"
      ])
      .where(qb => {
        contentArray.forEach(word => {
          qb.orWhere("Cos.content", word);
        });
        return qb;
      });

 const ingredientResponse = endResponse.map((object) => {
      for (const key in object) {
        if (object[key] === null || object[key] === undefined) {
          delete object[key];
        }
      }
      return object;
    });
```

Could someone give me some tips how I can improve the performance? I'm really confused if the problem is somewhere in the query, database or somewhere else and how to find it. Thanks a lot!!

**UPDATE**
Based on the comments, here is some additional information.

1. Here is an example of the output of

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM "Cos" LEFT JOIN "Actives" ON "Actives"."content" = "Cos"."content" LEFT JOIN "Alcohol" ON "Alcohol"."content" = "Cos"."content" WHERE "Cos"."content" = 'lactic acid'`
    Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.19..12.21 rows=1 width=355) (actual time=1.858..1.860 rows=0 loops=1)
   Join Filter: ("Actives".content = "Cos".content)
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.14..8.15 rows=1 width=304) (actual time=1.857..1.858 rows=0 loops=1)
         Join Filter: ("Alcohol".content = "Cos".content)
         ->  Index Scan using "Cos_pkey" on "Cos"  (cost=0.08..4.09 rows=1 width=61) (actual time=1.856..1.857 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (content = 'lactic acid'::text)
         ->  Index Scan using "Actives_pkey" on "Actives"  (cost=0.06..4.06 rows=1 width=243) (never executed)
               Index Cond: (content = 'lactic acid'::text)
   ->  Index Scan using "Alcohol_pkey" on "Alcohol"  (cost=0.06..4.06 rows=1 width=51) (never executed)
         Index Cond: (content = 'lactic acid'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.388 ms
 Execution Time: 1.949 ms
```

2. I'm measuring the time with google dev tools (section "Timing") and I'm looking at TTFB (time to first byte) - but I'm not sure if this is the right approach?!
3. As an example: I get the following result for `const inciListArray = [alcohol denat, sodium hydroxide]`

```js
const result = [ 
  {
  content: alcohol denat, 
  function: solvent, 
  translationPlant: null, 
  categoryAlcohol: Alcohol_1
  }, 
  {
  content: sodium hydroxide, 
  function: ph, 
  translationPlant: null, 
  categoryAlcohol: null
  } 
]
```

Comment: This is going to need more information 1) The output of the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` 2) Where are you measuring the response, on the server at the client? 3) What is the query string being returned by the above code?

Comment: I've updated my question. Please let me know, if you need any further information!

Comment: For 1) what is the actual query being run?  FYI the query executes in 49.926 ms, so you have to figure the 6-8s is coming from somewhere else. Your response to 2) does not actually say where the timing is being done? I was not clear enough on 3). What does the `knex("Cos") ...` return as the actual query string, not the query result?

Comment: Sorry! I misunderstood your questions :) I'm new in dev, so everything is a little confusing. Hope my update is a little more clear now? I don't know if 3) is the answer you're looking for?

Comment: The first query you posted was returning 28485 rows (fairly wide rows, too), so perhaps your performance issue is in the transmission and parsing of the result. Does having that many output rows make sense? Also, specifying exactly the columns you need instead of using `*` could be helpful.

Comment: For future reference this [Slow query questions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions) is a good starting point. The issue does not seem to be the query itself, but the display of the results. This could be due to network lag or more probably displaying the result set on the client end. GUI's often take a good deal of time to build the widgets necessary to show the data results.

Comment: The query plan you posted took 2ms and returned 0 rows.  If that is representative of your actual queries, then your problem is not in the database.